# Sklearn: Custom scorer on pre-defined split

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'd like to make sure my custom score function behaves as expected by comparing it to hand-computation (so to speak) on a pre-defined split using `train_test_split`.

However I can't seem to pass that split in to `cross_val_score`. By default it uses 3 fold cross-validation and I can't mimick the splits it used. I think the answer lies in the `cv` parameter but I can't figure out how to pass in an iterable in the correct form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pre-defined split, you can just simply train your model and apply the custom score function on the prediction of the test data to match the calculation. You do not need to use `cross_val_score`.

---

I'm pretty sure there's better and easier way but this is what I came up with as the `cross_val_score` documentation wasn't really clear.

You are right, it's about how you use the `cv` parameter and I used this format: `An iterable yielding train, test splits`.

The idea is to create an object that yields train, test split indices, and I referred: http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2015/holdout-cross-validation-generator/.

Assume that you already have a train test split. I used the `sklearn` built-in split and returned the indices as well:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid, indices_train, indices_test = train_test_split(train_X, train_y, np.arange(X_train.shape[0]), test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Then, I create a class to yield the train, test split indices using the output from `train_test_split`:

```
class HoldOut:

    def __init__(self, indices_train, indices_test):
        self.ind_train = indices_train
        self.ind_test = indices_test

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.ind_train, self.ind_test
```

Then you can simply pass the `Holdout` object to the `cv` parameter:

```
cross_val_score(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42, n_estimators=10), train_X, train_y, 
                cv=HoldOut(indices_train, indices_test), verbose=1)
```